# Did h2 and h3 change the phonetic reality of an adjacent *e in PIE under any circumstances?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, proto-indo-european

Did h2 and h3 change the phonetic reality of an adjacent *e in PIE under any circumstances? Can we treat *a and ā as allophones of *e in PIE?

Comment: the conditioning rules would be a little complicated to account for e's sandwiched between two laryngeals, but I believe that ought to be possible for PIE-proper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition yes. They're called the a-colouring and o-colouring laryngeals entirely because of the effect they had on adjacent **e*.

Denying phonemic status to **a/ā* is not universal, but it is done by the Leiden school, who analyse every **a* as **h₂e* and every **ā* as **eh₂*. This leads to a reconstructed language with very few vowels, but there are decent reasons to do it: **a* would be unusual in that doesn't participate in ablaut alternations (like **e*, **o*, **ē*, **ō* do), doesn't alternate with a glide (like **i/j* and **u/w*), and doesn't show up in suffixes or endings, and it just generally isn't needed.

Comment: The vowels and sonants were lengthened at the disappearance of the laryngeals, and the *a, *ā, *ī, *ū  were phonologized when the laryngeal disappeared. Since the *ī and *ū became vowel phonemes, can long sonants r̥̄, *l̥̄, *m̥̄, *n̥̄ also be regarded as independent vowel phonemes?

Comment: @i's Certainly not in PIE itself, but I don't think it's unlikely they existed at some stage of some (but definitely not all) daughter languages (e.g. possibly Indo-Iranian, definitely not Greek).

Comment: Yes. I think the long syllabic sonants were actually vowel phonemes at some stage of some descendant languages  (e.g. in Baltic and Slavic), which later were devocalized by arising a vowel (i or u) before them.))

Comment: Had the vowels and sonants been phonetically lengthened before the laryngeals disappeared but only after the disappearance of laryngeals they were phonologized or they were just lengthened after the disappearance of laryngeals? (Like the compensatory lengthening)

Comment: @i's All we can strictly say is that the laryngeals disappeared and the coloured vowels lengthened when they were followed by them; whether these changes happened concurrently or whether the lengthening happened before the loss (obviously it can't be the case that the laryngeals were first lost and then the lengthening happened afterwards) is not reconstructable, because all daughter languages show the same result. It's not typologically unusual for that kind of change to happen in a single step, so it's usually called compensatory lengthening as a shorthand even if it's not really knowable.

Comment: So is it more common to say that the vowels were lengthened ALONG WITH the loss of laryngeals when they were followed by laryngeals? (btw. How can I @ somebody in a common?)

Comment: @i's That's usually how it's phrased, yes, but it's understood that the lengthening could possibly have happened first. (If you type @ and then begin typing the person's name you'll get a pop-up thing you can click, at least on desktop. I'm doing it because I'm not sure if you're notified of my comment if I don't, but the person whose answer or question the comment is left on is always notified.)

Comment: Did the phonologized o, ō (under the influence of h3) and the "original" o, ō developed identically in descendant languages?

Comment: @i's The colouring of the vowels happened in late PIE, so there's no difference between an original *\*o* and an o-coloured *\*e*, but the laryngeals themselves sometimes left evidence in daughter languages (e.g. a stop followed by a laryngeal might become aspirated, &c.), with different languages showing different outcomes. That's a very big topic, though. I'm not sure I could come up with a solid and broad answer myself, but it might be worth asking as a separate question?

Comment: And what about the development of combinations "oH" and "Ho"? Did they also develop like *ō and *o? I have noticed that some textbooks of PIE don't give examples of "oH", is there not enough evidence for it?

Comment: @i's Again, the laryngeals sometimes left direct or indirect evidence in daughter languages. PIE *\*h₂owi-* 'sheep' (with an "original" *\*o*, not a coloured *\*e*) is reflected in Luwian as *hawi-*, so that's an example of *\*Ho* developing differently from plain *\*o*. There are circumstances in which *\*oH* should develop distinctly from *\*ō*, but I can't think of any attested examples. The Anatolian reflexes of *\*sóh₂wl̥* should show one, but unfortunately the only ones we (might) know of are hidden behind Sumerograms.

Comment: Sorry for my pedantic question. "The vowels and sonants i, u were lengthened when the laryngeals disappeared (when they before the laryngeals), and the relevant phones [a], [ā], [o], [ō], [i], [ī], [u], [ū] were phonologized along with the disappearance of laryngeals. In this way vowel phonemes *a, *ā, *o, *ō, *i, *ī, *u, *ū came into existence after PIE." Is this an acceptable argument?

Comment: @i's PIE already had *\*o* and *\*ō* as phonemes; all instances of both may have been phonologically conditioned at some earlier stage (in Pre-PIE), but they're no longer predictable in PIE. As for the rest, that's the situation in some daughter languages, presumably, yes; by definition, you can't make blanket statements about post-PIE as if it's a single language. Certainly Proto-Greek had all of those vowel phonemes, but e.g. Proto-Indo-Iranian only had three short and three long vowel phonemes, and how they got there *exactly* is hard to say.

Comment: @i's Insisting too hard on what is an allophone and what is a phoneme and when what became what is often unhelpful and, when you're dealing with reconstructions upon reconstructions upon reconstructions like this, unanswerable.